# Weblogic exception : javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'jdbc.payment'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'payment'

Tags: java, spring, jndi, weblogic12c

I have this exception when I lookup jndi datasource from weblogic from spring boot application...**only after one successful deployment**...I mean from the second deployment on.If I restart the container, it will work fine for the first deployment only.

Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'jdbc.payment'. Resolved 'jdbc'; remaining name 'payment'

the datasource with the same name and attached to the admin server.

I use docker image : store/oracle/weblogic:12.2.1.4-dev with environment variable **PRODUCTION_MODE=dev**

update : if I deattach the data source from the server then reattche it again then start the war, It runs successfully for one time againز

update : switched to local installation of weblogic not dockerized any more and the behavior still happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a spring issue...has nothing to do with weblogic.

In the war shutdown, Spring remove the data source form the server JNDI tree, however the data source still up and running on the server.
The action of recreating or even reattaching the data source to target server, add it again to the JNDI tree.

The workaround to solve this behavior is to prevent spring from calling the destroy method of the data source bean

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "dataSource",destroyMethod = "")
@Profile("weblogic")
public DataSource dataSourceWeblogic() throws NamingException {

        JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
        InitialContext ctx = (InitialContext) jndiTemplate.getContext();
        return  (javax.sql.DataSource) ctx.lookup(jndi);
}
```